# Java file reader isnt working, it wont run the bit of code

Tags: java, file, io, writer

I have this program that needs to read diffrent files for diffrent selected items in a JComboBox.  I have gotten the JComboBox and everything to work but now when i try to call the Course_loader code it wont run. Here is the code of where i try to call it from:

```
    public static String CourseName;
public static String PlayerName;
public Start_round(){
    try {
        Course_loader cl = new Course_loader();
        cl.loadCourse(CourseName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

And now here is the code of the file reader:

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class Course_loader {
public static String holes;
public void loadCourse(String s) throws IOException{
    File f = new File("courses\\"+s+".txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    holes = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();
    System.out.println("it ran");
}
```

}

When ever i call the code it dosnt print out the "it ran". I have checked over my code my self but i am new to the File reader stuff. Please help. Thanks in advance.

oh and the file is there and it has these words in it

```
    test
```

and when ever it try to print the string it is null which proves that the stuff isnt running.

Comment: no exceptions being thrown? If the System.out code is never reached then there is likely an exception being thrown before that code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're silently ignoring `IOException`.

Change the exception handling in `Start_round` to this:

```
try
{
    // your "load course" code ...
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should generate some output that will give you an idea of what's going wrong with the `FileReader` code, for example, *File not found* issues.

**Another tip:** Always put your `reader.close()` call in a `finally` block. In your case this means doing some specific exception handling in your `loadCourse` method. Search around for *java filereader*, and similar searches to look for best practices. Also, do some work learning about Exceptions, try/catch/finally if you don't understand that stuff very well.

Comment: great. See my edit about close() in a finally. Look around for links to example code for more thorough file reading patterns for java.

Answer (score 0):

```
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Your problem is right there. *Never* do that. At least log the exception. You are pretending to yourself that nothing went wrong and now you are wondering why it doesn't work.